# Regex Replace or Remove in Liquid Syntax

Tags: liquid, dotliquid

Can We have something in Liquid syntax for following

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"[^a-zA-Z0-9_. ]+", RegexOptions.Compiled);
string result1 = r.Replace("input text", "replacement text");
```

Which basically do a Replace or Remove?